# Using EasyMock 3 IMockBuilder with Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, mocking, easymock

I've been looking into using EasyMock 3's IMockBuilder as a means of generating partial mocks (I know partial mocking may suggest a design flaw, but I'm writing tests for old code).  Presumably I can use the deprecated static EasyMock.createMock() methods to create beans in my Spring config, like this:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="createMock">
    <constructor-arg value="org.mypackage.MyClass.class" />
</bean>
```

When creating a partial mock using an IMockBuilder, I need to make several calls to addMockedMethod() in order to define the methods I want mocked.  Is there a way I can do this in a Spring XML configuration file?  Ideally I'd like all the dependencies of all my beans set by Spring, and don't want to have to override them in my test cases in order to pass in mock objects created in this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, XML config isn't capable of that sort of flexibility.

You have two options:

1. Write an implementation of `FactoryBean` which creates the mock, configures it, and returns the mock to Spring. See [Customizing instantiation logic with the FactoryBean Interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean).
2. Use `@Configuration`-style configuration in Java, instead of XML style configuration. This is the most flexible approach, and is generally better than XML config. See [Java-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)

Comment: We've already got a lot of XML configuration and I don't really want to mix it with annotation-driven configuration, but the FactoryBean approach meets my needs, so I'll use that.  Thanks very much!